# How to make this Sinatra code DRYer?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

These are my Sinatra routes. They pass the storename as an ActiveRecord class and the params with which my helpermethods do what they have to.

```
def self.get_or_post(url,&block)
  get(url,&block)
  post(url,&block)
end

get_or_post "/read" do
  jsonp(read(params[:store].constantize, params))
end

get_or_post "/create" do
  jsonp(create(params[:store].constantize, params))
end

get_or_post "/update" do
  jsonp(update(params[:store].constantize, params))
end

get_or_post "/destroy" do
  jsonp(destroy(params[:store].constantize, params))
end
```

It seems to me this can be made DRYer doing something like:

```
case route
when read, create, update, destroy
  jsonp(method(route).call(params[:store].constantize, params))
else
  # neglect or give error
end
```

How can I get this route variable, and is my use of `method(route).call` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
%w(read create update destroy).each do |action|
  [:get, :post].each do |method|
    send(method, "/#{action}") do
      jsonp(send(action, params[:store].constantize, params))
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: wow, this is short, readable and does just what it needs to, THANKS Uri

Comment: This sort of thing is what makes Sinatra fun.